# Sound Tracking in Android

Tags: android, audio

Android application [Sound Track](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schematiclabs.soundtracking&hl=en) is doing some following job.

- Listen the song/sound track
- Search the track from server
- Provide full detail about the track like movie name, album name, singer etc

My question is **Which type of mechanism they are using to track a sound/song?**

Answer (score 0):

- Record a small excerpt of the song using the microphone.
- Upload it to the server
- Run a matching algorithm against your excerpt and the precompiled database that you've made containing thousands of songs.
- Find the best match, and send the result back to the device.
- Show the information to the user

Comment: can you provide me such API for sound comparison??

Comment: @ChintanRathod Uh, such APIs are rarely open source and available for all to use. You'll have to compile the database of songs and write the comparison code yourself.

Comment: Oh.. then it will be bit complicated task for me. Let me search for that.